# Removing XML node with no Descendants

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have an XML file. I want to remove the `line_item` nodes which don't have any descendants.

```
<root>
  <transaction>
    <type>regular</type>
    <number>746576</number>
    <customer>
      <mobile>5771070</mobile>
      <email />
      <name>abcd</name>
    </customer>
    <line_items>
      <line_item>
        <serial>8538</serial>
        <amount>220</amount>
        <description>Veggie </description>
        <qty>1</qty>
        <attributes />
      </line_item>
      <line_item />
      <line_item />
      <line_item />
      <line_item />
      <line_item>
        <serial>8543</serial>
        <description>Tax</description>
        <qty>1</qty>
        <value>42.78</value>
        <attributes />
      </line_item>
    </line_items>
    <associate_details>
      <code>660</code>
      <name>xyz</name>
    </associate_details>
  </transaction>
</root>
```

I am using ASP.NET 4. Right now I am finding the `line_item` node and checking if it has elements.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Are you using LINQ-to-XML or the System.Xml classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copied Alex Filipovici's answer, with a bit modification:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
    xDoc.Descendants()
        .Where(d => d.Name.LocalName == "line_item" && !d.HasElements)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(e => e.Remove());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xDoc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
        xDoc.Descendants()
            .Where(d => 
                d.Name.LocalName == "line_item" && 
                d.Elements().Count() == 0)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(e => e.Remove());

        // TODO: 
        //xDoc.Save(savePath);
    }
}
```

A shorter (and faster) alternative is to use the following syntax:

```
xDoc.Descendants("line_item")
    .Where(d => !d.HasElements)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(e => e.Remove());
```